# Updating counter in database using transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql

To speed up sorting rows in `posts` table by for exmaple `viewsCount`, `commentsCount` and `lovesCount` I store counters for each of those parameters. However I am not sure if procedure of inserting data to database along with incrementing a counter is done right way. Here is what I do:

1. Begin transaction
2. Insert new row to table views (or loves, or comments).
3. Increment counter on parent table by 1.
4. Commit

My goal is to commit only when both points 2 & 3 succeeded to avoid situation where comment for example has been added and counter has not been incremented and vice versa.

I am not sure if I fully understand how transaction works in this example - what will happen when before transation commits another query also tries to update counter? Transaction will fail? Maybe I should use specific type of transation? For now I am using REPEATABLE READ.

Also can some one tell me if using transaction in this place will have impact on performance?

Comment: To avoid so many updates, you could have a lean table into which a record gets inserted for each view/love/comment. Then, at frequent intervals, update the posts table. This will work if you are not keen on instant updates to the posts table. The concurrent inserts to the lean table will not lock each other.

Comment: That is not an option as I need counters to be updates immediately. Though it is interesting solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is try it and see.

What you will find is that at step 3, when you `UPDATE` the parent table's counter, a row-level write lock is taken on the row being updated. Any other concurrent transactions will block on that lock when they attempt to `UPDATE`, until the first transaction (the one that got the lock) either rolls back or commits. Another transaction will then get the lock and proceed.

What this means is that your approach will work, but will greatly reduce concurrency. If your transactions are short and the parent objects aren't highly contended that might be OK, it depends a bit on your app.

Comment: Well basically I insert row like this `{ UserId: 123, PostId: 456 }` to table `loves, views` and same with `content` to table `comments`. Updating table posts is just incrementing one counter (views/loves/comments) by one (in table `posts`). So there is no transaction that WONT write-lock row and just rollback when one of the operations fails? And what about triggers? What will be a difference if I will implements triggers on tables `loves/views/comments` that will update counters?

Comment: @user606521 Counter rollback or increment-on-commit would be a cool feature - but no, there is nothing like a way to say "add 1 to this row when I commit and only if I commit". It makes no difference whether you use triggers or direct client SQL.

Comment: But trigger will be faster than two separate queries right? (p.s. something like migrations would be nice feature - for a query you just pass another query which "rollbacks" (aka migration "down" method) it...)

Comment: @user606521 Yes, a trigger will reduce round-trips so may be faster. Watch out for deadlocks. As for running queries on rollback, as there is no guarantee the query would succeed that'd never fly. A specific counter feature would be needed instead.